# How can I print 8x8 photos?

Tags: printing

I want to print 8x8 photos & artwork.

What kind of printer and what kind of paper do I need?

I assume I also need a paper trimmer, but should I use A4 paper?

If I use A4 paper, do I need to make 2 cuts? (A4 paper is 8.27 inches wide).

Is there some paper which is exactly 8 inches wide, so that I only need to make 1 cut?

Should I use an inkjet or laser printer?

Comment: How do you plan to display the 8x8 prints? Matted in a frame?

Comment: @MichaelC Yeah, in 8x8 frames

Comment: Why wouldn't you matte prints in frames? That's typically the way it is done. Have you ever gone to a gallery and seen prints in frames without a matte?

Comment: @Gimmethe411 If your printing 8x8, and using a matte, then your frames would be bigger than 8x8.  So it's hard to tell if you're using a matte or not. you say yeah, but 8x8 frames contradicts this.  Also if using a matte, you wouldn't need to trim them to exactly 8", the matte would cover them.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

**Consider having your photos printed at a photo lab.** They will take care of printer and paper selection. They will trim the photos if needed. Instead of purchasing and maintaining a printer and consumables, you can produce more images to send out for printing.

> How can I print 8x8 photos?

1. Load your image into an image editor, such as GIMP.
2. Crop it to a square.
3. Set the print size to 8"x8".
4. Turn on your printer.
5. Make sure it is connected to your computer.
6. Make sure it has ink (or toner).
7. Make sure it is loaded with paper.
8. Make sure options such as "fit to page" are disabled.
9. Print the square photo.
10. Trim the output to the desired size.

> What kind of printer and what kind of paper do I need?
>   Should I use an inkjet or laser printer?

You can use any color printer. Consider a high-resolution printer that uses pigment inks.

You can use any paper that is compatible with the printer. Consider high-quality, archival photo paper made for your printer.

> I assume I also need a paper trimmer

Yes.

> but should I use A4 paper?

A4 is fine.

> If I use A4 paper, do I need to make 2 cuts?

Two cuts if your printer prints edge-to-edge. Otherwise, four cuts.

> Is there some paper which is exactly 8 inches wide, so that I only need to make 1 cut?

There is 8x10 paper. Prices appear to be quite high. Depending on your printer capabilities, you may still need to make two or four cuts.

Answer (score 1):

Photo labs are cheaper and better than inkjets (walmarts costcos etc) printing 8x10

You need two cuts
A trimmer or (a straight edge a cutting pad and an exacto knife)

Common papers are A4 8x10 81/2x11
All rewuire 2 cuts

Inkjets costs MUCH. More each page but inkjets are better at making colors more accurately. It can be hard to get great laser prints, plus they can be shiny.

IF you like images enough to print. Get a photolab to do it. Pro paper
Pro printer $35,000
Pro inks
At LOW profits

They get ink at 10% you pay
They get paper at 10% your price

They can print and charge your same home cost and they still make money

You print mid quality paper 10c
Mid quality ink 50c
On a low quality $300 printer

Get PRO 8x10 $2 each
First 300 prints are cheaper than printer and trimmer and inks